# How to chain useLazyQuery hook in handler function

Tags: reactjs, react-apollo

I want to chain apollo useMutation and useQuery hooks in a handler function. I cannot seem to get the data property of the useLazyQuery hook to alias - or for that matter the mutation properties loading, error, data. I could get the same effect with useMemo, but I want to explore what I can do with the lazy query in a promise chain.

```
 const [email, setEmail] = useState('');
  const [password, setPassword] = useState('');

  const [requestLogin, { loading, error }] = useMutation(LOGIN_USER)
  const [getUserProfile, { 
    loading: loadingProfile, 
    error: errorProfile, 
    data: profileData 
  }] = useLazyQuery(GET_USER_PROFILE)

  const submitHandler = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault()
    requestLogin({
      variables: {
        email: email, 
        password: password
      }
    }).then(({ data }) => {
      console.log("INITIAL DATA", data)
      login(data.login.token, data.login.user)
    }).then(({ data, profileData }) => getUserProfile({
      variables: {
        account_id: data.login.user.account.id
      }
    })).then(profileData => {
      console.log("DATA", profileData)
      history.push('/')
    })
  }
```

Comment: It seems that the fetcher does not return a promise